# Count succesful value transitions

Tags: dataframe, awk

I have a data set that looks like:

```
2.0
2.6
3.2
2.9
3.8
3.5
3.9
3.4
4.0
3.3
2.8
2.9
```

I want to apply an upper and a lower bounds to the data set of 3.8 and 3.0. Using these bounds I would like to count the successful transitions from below 3.0 to above 3.8 but not instances where the data just surpasses 3.0. I would also like to count the reverse events where the data goes from above 3.8 to below 3.0 but not instances where it starts above 3.8 goes below 3.8 and then returns above 3.8.

Is there a way to do this with awk?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The rises and falls do not have to happen in one step only, right? As in, `4.0 3.3 2.8` is 1 fall, isn't it? In your case my understanding is that there is one rise (`2.9 3.8`) and one fall (`4.0 3.3 2.8`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk -v up=3.8 -v low=3.0 -c=0 '!f&&$0<=low{f=1}f&&$0>up{f=0;c++}END{print c?c:0}' file
1
```

Explanation:

```
# I'm using a variable 'f' (flag) to store if we are within a low -> up
# range or not. awk auto-initialized the variable with 0 for us. We have
# to initialize 'c', because it might otherwise not been set when no
# result is found
BEGIN {
    c=0
}

# set the flag if the current value <= the lower boundary
!f && $0<=low {
    f=1
}

# reset the flag if the flag is set and we surpass the upper boundary
# increment the count 'c'
f && $0>up{
    f=0
    c++
}
# Print c at the end of input. Note that c
END{print c}
```

Comment: Initialisation of `c` can be removed by doing `END{print c+0}`

Comment: @kvantour yeah, or `print c?c:0`. But I didn't like that and decided to initialize it. Looks cleaner

Answer (score 1):

What about this? `U` and `L` are passed in as the lower and upper bound, whereas logic of the code should be easy:

- if we are below `L` we are candidate for a rise
- if we are above `U` we are candidate for a fall
- if we are above `U` and we are candidate for a rise then we've risen
- if we are below `L` and we are candidate for a fall then we've fallen

```
< your_file awk -v L="3.0" -v U="3.8" '
{
if ($0 < L) { rising = 1 }
if ($0 > U) { falling = 1 }
if ($0 > U && rising == 1) { rises += 1; rising = 0 }
if ($0 < L && falling == 1) { falls += 1; falling = 0 }
}
END { print "r:", rises, " f:", falls }'
```

Comment: I like this answer because it accounts for the reverse order too

Comment: Wait! You answer (which I like more, ahah) could too, couldn't it, @hek2mgl?

Comment: I admit I wasn't really sure if I understood the OPs requirements right, therefore just posted the in order solution. Was surprised to get accepted :) . I'll add it later

Comment: Well, I'm not surprised, as you answer uses `awk` as it should be used, since it makes the checks using the condition, not the action. It's nicer!

Comment: I wouldn't say that conditional statements shouldn't be used in actions. Your code is readable, maintainable and therefore just fine! When it doubt I'd say that going for the more explicit, readable implementation over the idiomatic one is a good approach. Might be different if you want to attract upvotes on SO :) but this is really just random sometimes ...